# Define simple data classes as abstract , interface or just classes?

Tags: c#, class

Rather new to OOP..

I am gonna build a number of small applications that will support our main business.

These apps:

-Will need some common data classes

-The above classes may change in the future as far as properties are concerned (will add properties when ERP versions advance).

For example i have a class:

```
public class Lot
    {
        public string SSCC { get; set; }
        public InventoryItem Item { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionLocalLot { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionEnglishLot { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
        public string Shift { get; set; }
        public string WorkOrder { get; set; }
        public string ProductionLine { get; set; }
        public string BarcodeEAN14 { get; set; }
        public decimal Boxes { get; set; }
        public decimal Units { get; set; }
        public decimal Pieces { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public string LastUser { get; set; }
        public Warehouse LastWarehouse { get; set; }
        public string ProductionLot { get; set; }
        public string PalletSequence { get; set; }
    }
```

The above class will be used by almost all applications (Windows forms or ASP pages). Ihave put this definition in a separate file called CommonClasses.

Should i define these classes as Abstract or Interfaces better? In most cases these classes will  not include methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class should describe all of an object's properties as well as methods that can act upon it.  Not all are going to be used at once; but they are provided so that all the behavior is understood and state of an object can be tracked.

The class described in your code seems like a candidate for a concrete class.  It provides a set of properties that are stored in memory and act in relation to one object.  If you require additional functionality at a later point, you can `extend` the class to provide this.

If however, each instance of the class requires different implementation; then you should consider `abstract` class, or perhaps `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use concrete classes in your case if the change is common for all applications which are using these classes.

Comment: No changes are not gonna be common for all applications necessarily. your answer then would be abstract?

Comment: or i could go with just a concrete class ,add properties and then just "ignore" them wher i dont need them? No so beautiful though